# Creating GIT repository

Tags: git, repository

While typing git init command in the dictionary in does not open a new repository file in the folder It shows- "Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Users/User/Desktop/MyProject/.git/" however in the folder - MyProject there is no actual git repository created. Could you please advise?

I tried to create a git repository file; opened the particular folder; typed cmd in the name of the folder; it opened command prompt and I typed git init; no repository created..

Comment: There is already a repo. What makes you think there is none?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `.git` directory inside of your project. Delete it and try again

Answer (score 0):

**Open Your Folder**

```
C:/Users/User/Desktop/MyProject
```

Go to in the menu bar

[Enable hidden files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLdMg.jpg)

Delete the .git folder and Reinitialized git in the same folder

```
git init
```

After that your git is successfully initialized